# Is there any source of live ATC audio with subtitles?

Tags: air-traffic-control, radio-communications

I'd like to know if there is a way to hear ATC and pilots' communications, with subtitles.

Comment: With subtitles?   Who do you think could possibly add that much text to live audio??

Comment: I mean automatic subtitles such as the youtube subtitles option

Comment: I removed your second question completely: please ask only one question at a time. If you haven't already seen the [tour] it might be helpful to understand how this site works.

Comment: Not an answer, but if your goal is to understand what you're hearing then you don't need live audio to do that. You can listen to any ATC recordings with subtitles and use them to 'practice' and then eventually listen to live audio. Some subtitles may not be completely accurate but that's probably always going to be an issue, whether the audio is live or not.

Comment: A service that used automatic speech recognition to transcribe live ATC feeds could be useful for people with poor/no hearing.

Comment: Is there any way to ***authoritatively*** answer this question in the negative? My strong suspicion is that there are no such sites, based on (1) nobody being aware of one, (2) the very limited utility & high technical difficulty in implementing such a service, for a very slight audience within what is already a "niche" field. But can I say with certainty that there are none, at all, anywhere? Nope... no more than I can prove Bigfoot doesn't exist.

Comment: @RalphJ https://xkcd.com/1235/

Answer (score 2):

Not live with subtitles, but there are certainly plenty of ATC/pilot recordings on youtube
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=atc+conversations

Plus Live ATC streams. I can't access these (lousy cell phone coverage), give them a try.
https://www.liveatc.net/topfeeds.php

Comment: +1 Some of the ATC recordings on YouTube come with on-screen captioning and/or diagrams to help the viewer make sense of the events in the video.

Comment: I don't know if the question was edited after your answer, but they're asking for live ATC audio with subtitles, which none of your links provide.

Comment: Live captioning does not exist that I am aware of.  Live captioning is also not needed to get used to the conversation flow. Recorded with captioning will do.

Comment: Might be worth linking to the Android and iPhone apps for LiveATC: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.liveatc.liveatc_app&hl=en_US  https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/liveatc-air-radio/id317809458?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

If you want an easy way to read the standard communications rather than listening to them, the US National Transportation Safety Board (NTSB.GOV) reports have written Voice Cockpit Recorder (VCR) transcriptions at the end of the Report in an Appendix.

That will include communications with Towers, Centers, and other Aircraft. This is because the NTSB is legally prevented from releasing the audio recovered from the VCR. Recordings made from popular shows like "Maday" or "Air Disasters" are made by actors performing the written transcript and are not the the voices you would hear on the actual recorder from a given event.

This [CVR Handbook](https://www.ntsb.gov/investigations/process/Documents/CVR_Handbook.pdf) PDF explains how the data can be used by the NTSB.

Because this is a law, and specifically covered by that law is the reason why it cannot be requested via a Freedom of Information Act (FOIA) requests, unlike more mundane 911 calls.

Comment: Note that you **can** request radar replays and ground-recorded audio **from the FAA** for any given flight on any given day. These data will include all radio transmissions captured at the control position as well as controller-to-controller "landline" coordination. They are stored for some length of time, possibly 45 days or possibly much longer (the low-bandwidth audio recordings don't take up *that* much space). Recordings associated with an aircraft accident are kept indefinitely (I believe) but those may in fact be un-FOIA-able—I'm not sure.

Comment: @randomhead I made specific reference to the CVR in my answer because those have transcripts that the OP wanted to see. They were not asking for audio recordings. Please read the post before making unrelated comments about the topic of my answer. CVR transcripts are professionally prepared and will not have the same errors that auto generated "Closed captioning" style solutions will contain based on word strings not in common every day non-airline use.

Comment: If OP is asking for **recordings *with* subtitles** then your answer is just as useless as my comment on it.